# Azure.Data.Tables serialization using F#

Tags: azure, f#

I am following this article to move data from an Azure data table.  Here is a copy of my type:

```
type GameId(x, y, z, q, r) =
    let mutable etag = x
    let mutable partitionKey = y
    let mutable rowKey = z
    let mutable timeStamp = q
    let mutable id = r
    interface ITableEntity with
        member this.ETag with get() = etag and set(v) = etag <- v
        member this.PartitionKey with get() = partitionKey and set(v) = partitionKey <- v
        member this.RowKey with get() = rowKey and set(v) = rowKey <- v
        member this.Timestamp with get() = timeStamp and set(v) = timeStamp <- v
    member this.Id with get() = id and set(v) = id <- v
    new() = GameId(ETag(),null,null,Nullable<DateTimeOffset>(),null)
```

When I run it, I get 0 data populating the data structure.

[image]

What do I have to do to get the data to populate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am following this [**blog**](https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/azure-tables-with-f/) . By using this I can be able to ***add*** the data and ***retrieve*** the data from the `Azure Data Table`.

If you try to customize of the model properties it automatically serialized. Decorating a model property with the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute will ignore it on serialization and the `[DataMember(Name = "some_new_name")]` will rename the property.

Refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/CHANGELOG.md#1220-beta1-2021-08-10) for more info